# Веб программирование для новичков

Tags: веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток, с недавних пор углубился в понимание вопросов смм и понял ,что без веб программирования заняться тем, что мне интересно не выйдет.
Итак созрел конкретный вопрос: с чего начать? Я никогда не имел дел с программированием в общем в том числе и с веб. Не велика ли пропасть и можно ли научится веб программированию не зная основ бэсика, СС+ итд? Если да, то хотелось бы услышать советов матерых девелоперов и программеров с чего начать! Ссылочки на бд,учебники и материалы для нубов:)Заранее всем огромное спасибо!:)

Comment: ЭМ, а как СММ(SMM - Social media marketing) связан с программированием?? СММ мастеру не нужно вникать в программирование, ему надо понимать как продвигать что либо в соц. сетях.

Comment: Знал что такого рода вопросы появятся:)Ну вот так распорядилась судьба, что мне мало лишь продвижения продукта. Мне хочется создать и породить свое детище, тем более,на данный момент для работы в интересных проектах требуется знание хотя бы основ веба, коих у меня нет. А себя в перспективе я хотел бы видеть себя как тех-евангелиста, умеющим не только разработать определенный продукт но и качественно его продвинуть не прячась за бородой и свитером с олениями(искренне считаю эти атрибуты девелоперов шикарными).

Comment: Вопрос в том, что мне интересно это направление и искренне хотелось бы заниматься веб-разработкой! и маленький upd : просьба не отсылать меня гуглить и плясать с бубном, т.к прошерстив много инфы понял,что нужно мнеие профессионалов области, и авторитетные\начитанные методики или издания. Денег на курсы у меня нет,да и я не считаю себя настолько глупым,что не смогу усвоить материал по учебникам.С детства занимался железом , и знаю его достаточно хорошо, а вот с программирования никогда не касался,как выясняется оч зря!(

Comment: > с недавних пор углубился в понимание вопросов смм

Вы СММ я так понял не доума поняли и уже в программисты! Маркетолог-Программист ни рыба ни мясо... Послушайте здоровую критику и сделайте выводы!

Comment: Что касается смм это хобби которое открыло глаза на некоторые вещи,по образованию я маркетолог но в инсте учили немного другому.Развелся с женой,детей нет,мне 24 дома куча свободного времени,дота\фильмы\порнушка\бухашки с друганами не манят. Поэтому рвусь в ряды ваши,не думаю,что в данном случае инициатива наказуема=\

Answer (score 3):

Основа любого сайта - это `html`, `css` потом можно заняться `javascript`, `php`, кроме того после того как более менее познакомишься с `html`, `css` то осваивай и движки такие как `joomla`, `wordpress`

Comment: Спасибо огромное буду иметь в виду.Можете посоветовать качественные ресурсы\чтиво для саморазвития по html?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала - HTML и CSS (вёрстка), можно начать на http://htmlacademy.ru
Потом будет полезно JavaScript - клиентское программирование, можно на javascript.ru и codeacademy поучиться. Для удобства можно изучить JQuery
Затем - серверное программирование: PHP/Python. Опять же есть курсы на codeacademy.
А после практики - статьи и книжки.

Answer (score 0):

Поставь главное перед собой задачу,которую хочешь достичь.И достигай,мануалы в помощь

Купи себе книг каких нибудь,всё равно от корки до корки не прочтёшь.Я так php уже неплохо знаю,но нет предела совершенству)

Comment: Это понятно)цель стоит) вопрос в том, с чего начать , я как начал смотреть возможные варианты слегка впал в ступор имхо "Руби он Рейлс или Питон на Джанго, jQuery/JS,+MySQL" итд звучит примерно как лалала иди продвигай свои дейтинг аппы...

Comment: начни с js,на codeacademy.com

Comment: Спасибо)Только что зарегался там:)пишу имена,считаю 2+2)

Answer (score 0):

Начните с Python, простой язык для веба и не только.

Comment: Спасибо! На данный момент,я думаю,для уровня качества моего восприятия как раз подходит codeacademy.com там вроде бы все есть,что на данный момент требуется для начала изучения в.т.ч и питона:)